# How to add a post-login information to an authenticated user?

Tags: python, django

I am using out of the box django 1.5 authentication solution. After authenticated, i want to add a 'post_login_info' to the user using user_logged_in signal from django.contrib.auth.signals

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)    
def post_login_action(sender,user,request,**kwargs):
    user.post_login_info = 'my post login information'
```

However, i can not retrieve user.post_login_info from request object later as follow:

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
def get_queryset(self):
    self.request.user.post_login_info  # Attribute Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'post_login_info'
    ...
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: what is `post_login_info` ?

Comment: I have a manyToMany relationship between User and the Store that she belongs to. post_login_info should be cur_login_store instead. It is easy if she only belongs to one store since I don't need user interaction to figure this out. How to handle the case when the user belong to multiple store is another obstacle i have not figure out so i move on with this temporary solution (only allow one user per store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `User` object have a `post_login_info` member? If so, you should call `user.save()` after you set `post_login_info`.

If not, you'll have to find some other way of persisting that information. One possibility could be Django's [session storage mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), a [customized User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) with a `post_login_info` member, or a new model (e.g. `PostLoginInfo` with a foreign key to User.

Comment: Session storage seems like the appropriate use for this question.

Comment: Session storage is what i am looking for. However, it still bugged me how user.post_login_info is lost. Thank you!